# Login required after resume from black screen

Tags: gnome, settings

When my computer screen is off after a while, login is required to go into the desktop. I'm activating automatic login, so when I turn on or reboot the computer, no login is required.

How can I disable login screen when resuming from black screen mode ?
I'm using gnome shell 3.18

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Activates >> Settings >> Privacy >> Screen Lock, Then click on the toggle switch next the text that says "Automatic Screen Lock". Press the button that says Close, and now the item that says "Screen Lock" should have "Off" next to it.

Comment: one last issue : the login is required when resuming from suspend; how disable it ?

Comment: If you are wanting disable all the lock screens and have the system not lock at all this should be the line you paste in the terminal `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen 'true'`